# Linux unequal cost multipath routing

Tags: linux, routing, linux-networking

Tried unsuccessfully to find any documentation on the issue but couldn't find any... Is there any way to implement this in a standard Linux distribution machine? My use case is something like a server with 4 NICs, a 40Gbps, 2 * 10Gbps, and 1Gbps. I would like them all to be utilised but ECMP doesn't solve the issue as the hash doesn't take link speed into considerations (as far as I'm concerned).

Update - I can see some functionality in BGP and EIGRP but would rather use a native Linux utility (iproute2 etc.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, and ive played much with this but have you looked at Linux bonding (modes 5 and 6) - ie bonding everything into 1 high speed channel?

Comment: Not sure I understood... Does bonding know how to take advantage of different speeds? I think that mode 5 only looks at interface usage which could be an issue if the implementation just makes sure they are all equally used (speed instead of percentage). Have you ever tested this?

Comment: I've not played with it, but the description of those modes implies the loads are balanced according to capacity, but I could have misunderstood.